# How can I make windows 10 to display the battery status of the laptop

Tags: windows-10, battery

I was under the impression that the status of the battery is always displayed in the icons on the bottom right of the windows 10 GUI. This was the case as far as I remember.

Now I cannot find the battery status icon anymore. Can anyone tell me how to get it (back)? I just want to have a simple way to know the status (how much charge) of the battery.

Comment: If you press the "up-arrow" in the right corner of your screen (before the other icons there), can you find it in that popup?

Comment: @Alive. No, there are 12 other icons there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when you start your windows it doesn't load the battery status icon. Restarting it will fix it.

You can try:

Go to device managers>Actions>scan for hardware changes and make sure you see-

1.Microsoft AC Adapter

2.Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery.

Then restart your pc.

Comment: Simple. And it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `taskbar`.
- Select `Customize the taskbar`.
- Scroll down to `Notification area`.
- Select `Select which icons appear on the taskbar`.
- Turn on `Always show all icons in the notification area` and/or turn on `Power`.
- Select the "back" button at upper-left to return to `Taskbar` settings.
- Scroll down to `Turn system icons on or off`.
- Turn on `Power`. **Wait, I just did that above!!** *Thanks to the intricacies of MS Windows setting, that icon can be made to disappear from two different locations in Settings.*

Also, make sure there is sufficient room to display the icon. At least temporarily, stretch the Taskbar to accommodate more rows.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I checked it and Power is already on. But apparently it is not effective. Is there anything else which could overrule this setting?

Comment: @ichbinsehselber, another Setting has been added. And, as mentioned above, sometime Windows just does not display the icon until a service is stopped and then restarted. BTW, there's always help at SuperUser; you're not working by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

To re-enable the battery icon so that hovering over it shows the remaining level
and estimated time (both are wildly inaccurate):

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power`
- Delete the items `EnergyEstimationEnabled` and `UserBatteryDischargeEstimator`
- Right-click and Add a New DWORD (32-bit), and name it `EnergyEstimationDisabled`
  of default value `0`
- Restart the computer for the changes to take effect.

For more information and screenshots see the article
[How to Enable Remaining Battery Time in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/405868/how-to-enable-remaining-battery-time-in-windows-10/).

(Note that Windows 10 is constantly changing and may in the future invalidate
this method. Microsoft doesn't like battery estimates since they are
inaccurate.)